# плескать / плескаться

Tags: выбор-слова

I can't understand the difference between the these words.

Is there one?

**Edit: 
I know all about intransitive and transitive verbs, but my dictionaries say that плескать can be intransitive too. 
"Волны плещут о борт корабля"
"вода плеснула"**

That's were the confusion is for me.

Comment: +1 to "I know all about intransitive and transitive verbs"

Comment: _-ся_ denotes reflexive verb, transitivity is not really relevant here

Answer (score 4):

"Плескать" (perfective "плеснуть") means 'to splash some liquid somewhere or at someone', like in

> Он плеснул ей в лицо водой. - He splashed water into her face.

Like this:

On the other hand, "плескаться" is something one can do alone, to bathe and splash water around.

> Ребёнок плещется в ванне. - A baby is splashing in the tub.

Like this:

or it can mean two people bathing and splashing at each other or more people bathing and splashing at one another.

> Школьники плескались в фонтане. - Pupils were splashing in the fountain.

Like this:

Comment: Cool answer—pictures, yea!)

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, there is.

The former is *transitive* (can have a direct object), whereas the latter is *intransitive* (used without a direct object).  In fact you can say that the latter is the same as the former with "self" as the object (the postfix '-ся' called "reflexive" postfix, formed from "себя" = "oneself").

Here is the verb "плескать" with a direct object:

> Днепр сердито **плескал** *волнами*.

The verb "плескаться" can be used in different shades of meaning.  From the recent news:

> Бегемот-малыш с удовольствием **плескался** в бассейне зоопарка.
>   На северном полюсе Марса когда-то **плескался** океан.

The first sentence, the baby hippo *splashed* with pleasure in a zoo pool.  In the second, an ocean *splashed* on Mars' Nothern pole some eons ago.  Both mean (in Russian) that the subject "splashed **itself**".

Comment: The dictionary says that плескать can be intransitive too.

 "Волны плещут о борт корабля.."